# Proper Setup of jaybird/Firebird DataSource with HikariCP

Tags: jdbc, firebird, hikaricp, jaybird

I'm trying to build a successful connection to a Firebird DB running on Windows using Spring Data JPA, Hibernate and a HikariCP Connection Pool.  I have gotten everything to run correctly on other JDBC compliant DBs (H2, Derby, MySQL, etc.) but when I switch my driver .jar over to Firebird I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.application.Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.application.Application.main(Application.java:43)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Property url does not exist on target class org.firebirdsql.ds.FBSimpleDataSource
```

Here's an extract of my Spring application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.provider=org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName=org.firebirdsql.ds.FBSimpleDataSource
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url=jdbc:firebirdsql:server:/db/test123.GDB?charSet=UTF-8&amp;roleName=USER;
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user=SYSDBA
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.handling_mode=delayed_acquisition_and_hold
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
```

I have tested using a few of the other Firebird classes that appear to implement javax.sql.DataSource for the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName property but all give variations of the cannot connect Exception.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This answer concerns a non-standard configuration in Spring Boot; the normal configuration should be done through the `spring.datasource.*` properties (see [Working with SQL Databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) in the Spring Boot documentation).

The HikariCP configuration properties under `dataSource` must match the properties available on the target data source, and the class `org.firebirdsql.ds.FBSimpleDataSource` has no property `url` (as reported by the error *"Property url does not exist on target class org.firebirdsql.ds.FBSimpleDataSource"*)

See the [`org.firebirdsql.ds.FBSimpleDataSource` javadoc](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.x/docs/org/firebirdsql/ds/FBSimpleDataSource.html) for a list of available properties. Specifically, you'll need to configure [`database`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.x/docs/org/firebirdsql/ds/FBSimpleDataSource.html#setDatabase-java.lang.String-), [`charSet`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.x/docs/org/firebirdsql/ds/FBSimpleDataSource.html#setCharSet-java.lang.String-) and [`roleName`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.x/docs/org/firebirdsql/ds/FBSimpleDataSource.html#setRoleName-java.lang.String-).

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSource.database=server:/db/test123.GDB
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSource.charSet=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSource.roleName=USER
```

The connection properties must be set explicitly on the data source: you can't provide those properties in the `database` property (which is in essence the JDBC URL without the `jdbc:firebirdsql:` prefix and without properties).

I have created improvement ticket [JDBC-521](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/issues/217) to add a `url` (or maybe `jdbcUrl`) property that accepts a full JDBC URL in a future version.

---

<sup>For those interested, see the follow-up discussion on [HikariCP Connection Pool won't connect to Firebird DataSource](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-java/2018/2/11404.html)</sup>

Comment: Hi Mark,

`code`
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url] not found

Comment: If I put the url key back in to satisfy Hikari, then I'm back to:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Property url does not exist on target class org.firebirdsql.ds.FBSimpleDataSource

Comment: This seems to be less straightforward than I expected. I'm not sure why JPA would require presence of this specific property, as the JDBC specification does not define this property at all (JDBC only requires existence of a `description` property).

Comment: Could you update your question to include exactly what you're using (Spring or Spring boot, versions), then I will try to reproduce this, and see if I can fix it with a little more priority. As a workaround, you could try to  extend `FBSimpleDataSource`, and add a `getUrl`/`setUrl` property that does nothing.

Comment: It was simple enough.  My starting point is a very simple Spring JPA/Hibernate/HikariCP demo connecting to a local H2 database.  The complete source can be found here: 
https://github.com/juliuskrah/java-crud/tree/spring-data-hibernate-jpa
I just switched it to a gradle project, removed H2 drivers, switched to jaybird and switched url, driver and connect info to an entity defined in our DB.  I will try the extends to see if that helps.

Comment: I can provide complete project if desired.  It's very small.

Comment: @blyons Scanning through that project, the problem could also be one of that example project itself, in class `com.tutorial.Application`, it explicitly tries to copy property values using `getRequiredProperty`, changing how that properties object is populated may help.

Comment: I'm not sure what mods to make there.  I did try the simple extension on FBSimpleDataSource.  I'm getting complaints now on a nonexistent method "" (Nice right - a reference to a method that can't be found).  Do I have to new an instance of the FBSimpleDataSource in my class and then write delegate methods in my class to call each of the methods in FBSimpleDataSource?

Comment: PS - Boss says thanks for the quick help.  My company is a Firebird Platinum sponsor.

Comment: I think we may have reached a point where it would be better to take this problem to the Firebird-Java mailing list, as that is probably a better venue for troubleshooting than comments here on SO. Could you post a recap there, and maybe provide some more information on the problem with the subclass.

Comment: Spring basically prefers JDBC URL-based configuration rather than DataSource-based.  Try omitting the ``dataSourceClassName`` property and using ``jdbcUrl`` property instead.  In that case, you *may* have to specify the ``driverClassName``, but try without it first to see if the DriverManager can resolve the driver based on the URL.

Comment: Note, even with URL-based configuration, you can typically still use ``dataSource`` properties.  These are translated into a ``Properties`` set that is passed to the driver.  ``dataSource.charSet=UTF-8`` will result in a ``charSet`` property with value ``UTF-8``.  See here ["Illustration 2.3"](https://firebirdsql.org/file/Jaybird_2_1_JDBC_driver_manual.pdf) for equivalency.

Comment: How can i activate PreparedStatement caching in each connection with Jaybird 2.2.15, created by Hikari? For example, i have a pool with 5 connections and want to each of them have ability to support prepared statement caching.

Comment: @lanmaster That would have been better to ask as a new question than in a comment on an unrelated question. The answer however is, you can't: HikariCP doesn't provide statement caching, and neither does Jaybird itself.